# How do I make buttons go across horizontal vs. stacking & make them 50% (2 by 2) on mobile?

Tags: html, css, svg, grid, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the following look for desktop & mobile -
[image: Desktop & Mobile]

Here is what I have so far -

```css
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1170px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height:100vh;
    }
    
    .button {
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
    /* ---- Intro ---- */
    
    #intro {
        background: #ff6400;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 4em 0;
    }
    
    #intro .cta {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    #intro .cta .splash {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id='intro'>
    <div class='cta container'>
        <div class="herosvg-container"><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/407.svg" width="100%"></div>
        <p>Delectus illum corporis laundantium illo repudiandae et doloemque.</p>
        <a class='button' href='#'> <span>SHOP NOW</span> </a>
        <a class='button' href='#'> <span>SHOP NOW</span> </a>
        <a class='button' href='#'> <span>SHOP NOW</span> </a>
        <a class='button' href='#'> <span>SHOP NOW</span> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to avoid running into the issue where the buttons might overlap the svg, or vise versa. Also I'd like the ability to control the width of buttons and svg separately while being able to say "i want to float the svg and buttons to the left or right of the hero."

If you have any ideas or can point me to the right direction you would be a life saver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the links in their own container. You'll find it much simpler to display them as you require using flexbox on **that** container.

Media queries do the rest.

Full Page - Buttons to side

[image]

Small Page - Buttons underneath in row

[image]

Mobile - Button underneath in *wrapping* rows

[image]

A quick example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button-wrap {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .button-wrap {
    padding: 1em 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  button {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  button {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero"><img src="http://www.placebacon.net/1200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Example**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jaRwdW)

Answer (score -1):

Adding a min-width to your buttons should cause them to wrap when they get smaller than that width.

I believe all the buttons will be the same width, but if not you could add `width: 50%` to the buttons inside a media query for smaller screens.